# What is a Latin Square?

Tags: definition, latin-square

I have recently seen a problem that used the term "latin square". I was wondering, what is a latin square? I know that it is actual square. Is a latin square a square like a Sudoku puzzle or is it where the rows and columns add up to the same number?

Comment: How about reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square)

Comment: What do you mean by "types of latin squares"?

Answer (score 1):

It is a common puzzle: a grid filled with symbols.  As many symbols as there are rows / columns.  Each row and column must contain all of the symbols exactly once.

[Latin Square (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square)